# How do I use a different column name for the ID for the Inherited JPA class

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance

Similar to [Hibernate : How override an attribute from mapped super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257921/hibernate-how-override-an-attribute-from-mapped-super-class) and [Inheritance and @AttributeOverride on @Id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811343/inheritance-and-attributeoverride-on-id-field) but with a simpler case.  I just want to change the name of the class

[image: ER]

```sql
CREATE TABLE `billing_target` (
  `billingTargetID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `targetType` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `targetID` int(11) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`billingTargetID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Client` (
  `clientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200),
  PRIMARY KEY (`clientID`)
);
```

Here's my attempt so far

```
@Data
@Entity
public class BillingTarget implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "BillingTargetID")
    private Integer id;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
@DiscriminatorValue("CLIENT")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@AttributeOverride(
    name = "id",
    column = @Column(name = "ClientID")
)
public class Client extends BillingTarget {
    private String name;
}
```

However, my queries are looking for `Client.BillingTargetID` rather than `Client.ClientID`

Since I `@AttributeOverride` it is ignored.

> @AttributeOverride or @AttributeOverrides in conjunction with entity inheritance is not supported:

If I make `BillingTarget` a `@MappedSuperclass` I would get

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1745)

Comment: This is a classic example of why I insist on the primary key column being named `id` in all cases. There's every reason to, and just no good reason not to. If it needs to be *rendered* as "clientId", that's a concern for the UI layer and should affect correct database design and adhering to standards.

Comment: Legacy DB.  Just trying to map the JPA onto it.  It's actually worse than what I wrote there.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637339/how-to-map-a-onetoone-with-zerooronetoone-back-reference-in-jpa the actual thing was a targetID but I found out I that BillingTargetID and TargetID are always equal.